# How can I get a deep copy of a Bundle?

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to have 1 copy of bundle which was at the beginning of activity.

If I want to undo the changes done by user in the activity, Then I can just get the 
bundle which was at the beginning and I can modify the same.

I tried using bundle.deepCopy() , But the api is supported from 26 on-words.

So how I can achieve that.
(To hold 1 copy of bundle which was at the beginning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest not changing the bundle. Instead read the bundle into local variables and change those.  Its much more convenient.

Short of that, loop over all the keys of the original bundle and build a new one from it at the beginning, and modify only that new one.

Comment: Yaa. I tried the same . It works. I am creating a new bundle when I want to reset and putting the required initial values at the time itself.